# MySQL select rate of change on energy counter given sampling time

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL Table where the absolute value of an energy meter (counter) is logged. New rows are added automatically every increase of 5 of value or at the latest every 15 minutes.

The table data could look something like this:

```
id   value     time
1    2500      21.12.16 01:09:52
2    2505      21.12.16 01:10:23
3    2510      21.12.16 01:11:00
4    2512      21.12.16 01:26:00
...
1500 4502      22.12.16 00:00:03
1501 4507      22.12.16 00:00:58
...
3456 6528      23.12.16 00:00:10
3457 6533      23.12.16 00:05:22
```

Given a start time, end time and sampling time, is it possible to get the difference between values?

For example,

```
start_time = 21.12.16 02:00:00
stop_time  = 21.12.16 03:15:00
sampling_time = 15 minutes
```

Should do the following:

```
Get value at start_time (or closest to it) = value1
Get value at start_time + sampling_time (or closest to it) = value2
Select difference between value1 and value 2
Get value at start_time + 2*sampling_time (or closest to it) = value3
Select difference between value 2 and value 3
... so on, until start_time + n*sampling_time > stop_time
```

Expected result could be something like this:

```
20     //Difference between value 1 at 2:00 (or closest) and value 2 at 2:15 (or closest)
18     //Diff. between value 2 (2:15) and value 3 (2:30)...
23     
15
45     //... Diff. between value n-1 (3:00) and value n (3:15)
```

Is this with pure SQL possible? Or should I log the consumed energy on a different way?

Answer (score 2):

I began by creating the table and inserting the first few rows to make, so that you will have an understanding of the table schema I'm using. Notice that the `id` is considered as `PRIMARY KEY` value.

```
CREATE table t1(
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY, 
  `value` int,
  `time` timestamp
)Engine=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
   (1,2500,'21.12.16 01:09:52'),
   (2,2505,'21.12.16 01:10:23'),
   (3,2510,'21.12.16 01:11:00'),
   (4,2512,'21.12.16 01:26:00');
```

The query you are asking for is a subtraction between 2 different queries:

Query 1: `select value from t1 where time = **smaller_timestamp**`

Query 2: `select value from t1 where time = **larger_timestamp**`

To Get the result: `SELECT query1 - query2`;

Example:

```
-- smaller timestamp 
mysql> select value from t1 where time ='21.12.16 01:09:52'; 
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|  2500 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-- larger timestamp
mysql> select value from t1 where time ='21.12.16 01:26:00'; 
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|  2512 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT (select value from t1 where time ='21.12.16 01:26:00')-(select value from t1 where time ='21.12.16 01:09:52') AS value_difference; 
+------------------+
| value_difference |
+------------------+
|               12 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

More generically you can use methods like `DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL)` utilize different start/end times.

Example: For this case i used time='21.12.16 01:11:00' and INTERVAL=15 minutes.

```
mysql> SELECT 
    -> (select value from t1 where time =DATE_ADD('21.12.16 01:11:00', INTERVAL 15 minute))-
    -> (select value from t1 where time='21.12.16 01:11:00') 
    -> AS 
    -> value_difference;
+------------------+
| value_difference |
+------------------+
|                2 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I should let you know that if you want to do "closest to", then rather than using "=" you should use greater/less than comparison,  `ORDER BY`, and the function `LIMIT` rather than just a select.

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT 
    -> (select value from t1 where time<=DATE_ADD('21.12.16 01:11:00', INTERVAL 15 minute) ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1)-
    -> (select value from t1 where time<='21.12.16 01:09:52' ORDER by value ASC LIMIT 1)
    -> AS
    -> value_difference;
+------------------+
| value_difference |
+------------------+
|               12 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Per the request of @bishop, the following is an example of these queries as a stored procedure.

The first case is when there are 2 timestamps to compare from:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE calculateValue(startTime TIMESTAMP, endTime TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN
  set @startTime = startTime;
  set @endTime = endTime;

  set @resultStart=concat("SELECT value FROM t1 WHERE time <='",@startTime,"' ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1");
  set @resultEnd=concat("SELECT value FROM t1 WHERE time <= '",@endTIME,"' ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1");
  set @query=concat("SELECT (",@resultEnd,")-(",@resultStart,") AS 'value_difference'");
  prepare stmt from @query;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The second case is when using the `DATE_ADD` function.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE calculateValue(startTime TIMESTAMP, timeInterval VARCHAR)
BEGIN
  set @startTime = startTime;
  set @timeInterval= timeInterval;

  set @resultStart=concat("SELECT value FROM t1 WHERE time <=DATE_ADD('",@startTime,"',INTERVAL ",@timeInterval,") ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1");
  set @resultEnd=concat("SELECT value FROM t1 WHERE time <= '",@endTIME,"' ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1");
  set @query=concat("SELECT (",@resultEnd,")-(",@resultStart,") AS 'value_difference'");
  prepare stmt from @query;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Well explained. Now, how can the OP use this technique to get a *set* of differences, one for each sample point in the interval?

Comment: To do the same process over and over, you would either need to create a method around it, either in SQL (stored procedures or triggers), or another language where `time` (and may also `value`) column(s) are variables.

Comment: Indeed. It is precisely the latter the OP is requesting and is missing from your answer.

Comment: Beginning at "Per the request of @bishop, the following is an example of these queries as a stored procedure. " is an example of stored procedure